# phpmyadmin underscore gives privileges to wrong database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Hello im new here and dont even know if stackoverflow is the right board for this question but i cant figure out my problem..

I got many databases in phpmyadmin and many database-specific users who got all privileges for their own database and can read some others.

Now i have a user abc with rights to all databases starting with the name :

```
abc_%
```

like `abc_development`, `abc_production`...

But if i create a new database `abc-def` for example, the old user got all rights to it and there is no distinction between `abc_` and `abc-`

Thank you very much and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An underscore (`_`) has a specific meaning in SQL, similar to `%`.... while `%` is a wildcard for matching any number of characters, `_` is a wildcard for matching a single character.

If you need to use a literal underscore in a query, then you need to escape it, in the same way you'd need to escape a literal `%`

so

```
abc\_%
```

Comment: thanks i also don't want to change the old user so my only possibility is to rename my new database disparate to abc

Answer (score 0):

In sql,  there are two wildcard characters.
"_" matches a single character.
"%" matches 0 or more characters.

Your query should say 'abc\_%' to work the way you expect it.